# Einstein Bot not able to transfer chat with omni routing skill based

Tags: einstein, omnichannel

I am trying to transfer chat to an agent but enable to do it, I have omnichannel routing.I did all the set up for omni-channel skill based routing.

Answer (score -1):

The [Spring 19 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_livemessage_skills_routing.htm) state that:

> Einstein Bots don’t support omni skills-based routing.